# Combine multiple rows into single row with JSON object as columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which I'm trying to reduce the dataset by combing all ID/Section combinations into a single row (where there are 3 total sections) with nested JSON. The table schema looks like:

```
| ID       | Section  | Country  | Date   |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ------ |
| 1        | 1        | US       | 1-1-11 |
| 1        | 2        | US       | 1-1-11 |
| 1        | 3        | US       | 1-1-11 |
| 1        | 1        | CA       | 1-1-11 |
| 1        | 2        | CA       | 1-1-11 |
| 1        | 3        | CA       | 2-2-22 |
| 1        | 1        | MX       | 2-2-22 |
| 1        | 2        | MX       | 2-2-22 |
| 1        | 3        | MX       | 2-2-22 |
| 2        | 1        | US       | 3-3-33 |
```

I would like to perform a query to transform this to something that combines id/section and the country and dates into a JSON string

```
| ID/Section | Country/dates                      |
| ---------- | ---------------------------------- |
| "1,1"      | {"US;CA":”1-1-11;","MX":"2-2-22;"} |
| "1,2"      | {"US;CA":”1-1-11;","MX":"2-2-22;"} |
| "1,3"      | {"US":”1-1-11;","CA;MX":"2-2-22;"} |
| "2,1"      | {"US":”3-3-33;"}                   |
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need two group by for that and concat needed columns.

First we group by id, section, date, after only by id and section.

```sql
select id || ',' || section as id_section, '{'|| listagg(temp, ',') || '}' as country_dates
from (select id, section, '"' || listagg(country, ';') || '"' || ':' || '"' || date || '"' as temp
      from test.temp
      group by id, section, date) as t1
group by id, section;
```

Comment: Is there a way to aggregate countries with the same dates?                                                      | "1,1"      | {"US;CA;BR:JP:GB":”1-1-11;","MX;AU;NZ":"2-2-22;"} |

Comment: @HanBrolo I think right now my code does it.